# django all auth file path installed locally?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to locate the location of django all auth package within my project. I installed it with an active virtual environment and ran a command to see the file path and its file path is /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allauth/**init**.py. This looks like its installed locally.

I tried installing with pip3 install django-allauth when virtual environment was active. Why isnt this installed within the lib folder in my virtual environment along with django?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.